# How to let Go find library headers?

Tags: go, cgo

I've been searching for a while but cannot find a solution to this issue.

Because libraries like SDL2 are not part of the OpenBSD operating system, they are stored in `/usr/local`. Go seems to be looking for headers in `/usr/include` and not `/usr/local/include`. I see flags in `go env`  but I'm unable to edit them.

Is there a way to resolve this issue without symlinks? Perhaps a Go equivalent of the `-I` flag common in C compilers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Cgo, you must use something like this:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/ssl/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lcrypto -L/usr/local/ssl/lib
*/
import "C"
```

In this case I'm using it to compile against the latest OpenSSL.  Edit to suit your needs.